# Elasticsearch get document by id when id is an URL

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a elasticsearch cluster with millions of documents. The unfortunate thing is the id is set as the user URL. The problem is I can get all documents through search or scroll API but when I try to get the document through ID which is how you check whether there is an document or not in your cluster, I get an 404 error although it is present.

```
{u'delete': {u'status': 404, u'_type': u'public', u'_index': u'index', u'_version': 1, u'found': False, u'_id': u'http://www.domain.com/user-1'}}
```

So, is there any way I can get the document by just doing

curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/index/public/http://www.domain.com/user-1'

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried encoding the ID?  `http%3A%2F%2Fwww.domain.com%2Fuser-1`

Comment: Yes. Did not work

Comment: encoding works, I tried `curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/index/public/http%3A%2F%2Fwww.domain.com%2Fuser-1'` and it is working. I am not sure why it is not working for you, what version of ES you are using? There is a very [old issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/2903)

Comment: I'm using latest elasticsearch
Version: 2.4.1, Build: c67dc32/2016-09-27T18:57:55Z, JVM: 1.8.0_102

Check the images below : http://imgur.com/rqq5yoJ
http://imgur.com/ky11U4x